# Pulling STDN for This Meta tag Script PHP

Tags: php, screen-scraping, meta-tags

I have a php script that pulls meta tag information of a web page.
I use this script from CLI.
My question is how do I add to this script that takes in the argument (url) and apply it to the script.  Again, this would be from the command line interface.

Here is the sample script.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

    function getMetaData($url){
        // get meta tags
        $meta=get_meta_tags($url);
        // store page
        $page=file_get_contents($url);
        // find where the title CONTENT begins
        $titleStart=strpos($page,'<title>')+7;
        // find how long the title is
        $titleLength=strpos($page,'</title>')-$titleStart;
        // extract title from $page
        $meta['title']=substr($page,$titleStart,$titleLength);
        // return array of data
        return $meta;
    }

    // This line should be replaced with the function call using argv    
    //$tags = getMetaData('$url');

    // Check data was passed
    if (empty($argv[1])) {
        exit("You didn't specify a URL!");
    }

    // Pass the supplied data into your code
    $tags = getMetaData($argv[1]);


    echo 'Title: '.$tags['title'];
    echo "\n";
    echo 'Description: '.$tags['description'];
    echo "\n";
    echo 'Keywords: '.$tags['keywords'];

?>
```

Much appreciate the help, I'm a php newbie.

Comment: Hi Jon, welcome to StackOverflow! Note that you can highlight your code by simply indenting it with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to address your question directly - you can access the command line arguments to your script through the [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) global variable.

`$argv` is a standard variable registered in the global scope, and not a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) like `$_GET` and `$_POST` etc - so it will not be available in your function unless you pass it in as an argument.

The first argument will be available in `$argv[1]`, the second in `$argv[2]`, etc etc.

Now to address a couple of points about your script:

- When extracting information from HTML in PHP, the best way to do it is with [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). This is a proper HTML parser for PHP and will allow you to do things like select all the `<meta>` tags in the document and extract the values of their attributes very easily.
- Your code is downloading the entire document twice - once at `get_meta_tags()` and once at `file_get_contents()`. This is obviously inefficient - but would be solved by using DOM because you would only need to create the document object once. Alternatively you could use `file_get_contents()` first and save the data to a temporary file, then call `get_meta_tags()` on that temp file.
- The closing `?>` tag in your script can (and usually should) be omitted. This prevents unexpected white-space being accidentally output at the end of your script.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of how to use `$argv`:

```
<?php

  // Check data was passed
  if (empty($argv[1])) {
    exit("You didn't specify a URL!");
  }

  // Pass the supplied data into your code
  $tags = getMetaData($argv[1]);

  // ...
```

Comment: appreciate the feedback, but I'm still not sure how to write it applicable to this script.

Comment: almost got it, i'm trying to apply it to the script, still not showing the meta info.  sorry newbie here

Comment: What is happening instead? Do you get any output? Can you show your full code?

Comment: @Jon You can edit your question with it, or if you prefer [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) is always good.

Comment: @Jon It looks like you copied across a mistake that I made in my first draft of the code with the wrong sort of quotes - this is totally my bad. I have just modified the code in your question slightly, try using that version instead and see what happens